# Which would be the easiest way to turn folder with C headers into folder with C++ headers?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, header

I am quite abeginner with all that C/C++ coding. Thay say that having C library with all headers turned into C++ in a fashon like:

```
   #ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" { 
#endif 

//.. header code 

#ifdef __cplusplus 
} 
#endif
```

Will make it possibe to esely use practicly any C lib from sources (modified in such way). So I thought I shall give it at least a try. but I found I have like more than 300 headers... Ofcourse I will not use all of them but any way I'd prefere to make job once. So haw can I add such code to all headers? (I work with Windows, VisualStudio 2010 and 2008)

Comment: You're not talking about the system headers are you, like stdio.h  and stdlib.h? Otherwise I can't imagine how you as a beginner would have 300 header files right from the start.

Comment: I am talking about FFmpeg=) I am just tired of using its bilds (my ones are crappy and my limited headers edition I created by hend... rrrrr) and want to use it from sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only really need to do that if you have prebuilt C library code you are trying to interface your C++ code to.

If you still have the sources and are going to build all that C code yourself, you may find it easier to just submit them to the compiler as C++ code. With some compilers it is as simple as renaming the source files to *.cpp.

If that isn't workable, what I'd do is start with what you have, and only bother to put the `extern "C"` stuff around routines you need to use directly from your C++ code **as you find them**. That will surely be much less than the full 300 files, right?

Comment: here we talk about VS... so can you provide info on how to submit C to the compiler as C++ code? Any readMes or links with images?

Comment: @Kabumbus - Well, with VS as I said I generally just rename the ".c" files to ".cpp" and go on my merry way. It looks like the /TPfilename option to the compiler will tell it that filename is a C++ file, regardless of its name though.